# React state with value of array, for multi checkbox values, mutate outside and after setState() to number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, checkbox, setstate

I'm new in react so excuse me if I looked repetitive but i couldn't find an answer online.
I'm working on react multi value checkbox form by pushing the checked value inside stat array, it's seem working well inside the setState function with first checked, when logged it in the console I received an array whit the new added value.
but directly after the setState() the array value changed to 1 !! and of curse I can't use any high-order functions anymore.

So any idea why that's happen, and how I can fix it ?!
[Please find screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o09eo.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nationality: [],
    };
    this.handelChecked = this.handelChecked.bind(this);
  }

  handelChecked(e) {
    let { name, value, checked } = e.target;
    console.log(name, value, checked);
    console.log(this.state.nationality);
    if (checked) {
      this.setState({
        nationality: this.state.nationality.push(value),
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.nationality);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.nationality);

    return (
      <>
        <form>
          <label>Nationality</label>
          <br />
          <label>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='nationality'
              value='Japaneses'
              onChange={this.handelChecked}
            />
            Japaneses
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='nationality'
              value='Dutch'
              onChange={this.handelChecked}
            />
            Dutch
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              name='nationality'
              value='Egyptian'
              onChange={this.handelChecked}
            />
            Egyptian
          </label>
        </form>
        <div>
          <br />
          <h4>Nationality:</h4>
          <p>{this.state.nationality}</p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: 1) Please post code as text, not images. 2) You're mutating state by calling `this.state.nationality.push()`. 3) State updates are async, so even if it updated correctly, the `console.log` immediately after the update will not have the updated value available.

Comment: `push` [returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). And please post code as code, not as a picture - let alone a link to a picture.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, it's seem a compeletly wrong approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please check the example below. I used setState with prevState, that is the main change for working the code. I also do one optional change that is, I removed `this.handelChecked = this.handelChecked.bind(this);` from constructor and use arrow function.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nationality: [],
        };
    }

    handelChecked = (e) => {
        let {name, value, checked} = e.target;
        console.log(this.state.nationality);
        if (checked) {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                prevState.nationality.push(value);
                return{
                    nationality: prevState.nationality
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(this.state.nationality);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form>
                    <label>Nationality</label>
                    <br/>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            name='nationality'
                            value='Japaneses'
                            onChange={this.handelChecked}
                        />
                        Japaneses
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            name='nationality'
                            value='Dutch'
                            onChange={this.handelChecked}
                        />
                        Dutch
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type='checkbox'
                            name='nationality'
                            value='Egyptian'
                            onChange={this.handelChecked}
                        />
                        Egyptian
                    </label>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    <h4>Nationality:</h4>
                    <p>{this.state.nationality}</p>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: thanks Khabir, it's work but duplicating the value, i got [Dutch, Dutch, Egyptian, Egyptian], I fix it as following         nationality: [...this.state.nationality, value],

Comment: `handelChecked(e) {
    let { name, value, checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      this.setState({
        nationality: [...this.state.nationality, value],
      });
    }
  }`

Comment: @Alaa, Why you did undo for Answer? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I didn't. I maybe by mistake

Comment: Oh no problem, I thought I had something wrong in my code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I fix the handelChecked() as following:

```
handelChecked(e) {
let { name, value, checked } = e.target;
if (checked) {
  this.setState({
    nationality: [...this.state.nationality, value],
  });
}
```